# IE8 - Content Not Acceptable Symfony 2 App

Tags: symfony, nginx, internet-explorer-8

I have a website up and running (and i need to support IE8).

Server: Nginx, framework Symfony2/PHP/MySQL

The issue is simple: IE8 (8.0.6) shows an **HTTP 406Content not acceptable** on all HTML pages.

Headers (Nginx)

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 25 Apr 2016 15:23:46 GMT
Server:nginx/1.6.2
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Debug-Token:d7e68f
```

HTML (2 versions, not working)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Htm 2</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
</head>
<body>
   ... hi
</body>
</html>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Htm</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
</head>
<body>
   ... hi
</body>
</html>
```

I have read tons of stuff on that matter but could not find any clue. The previous website version worked on IE8 and ran on `Apache 2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was not related to Nginx but to `Symfony 2` and `FOSRESTBundle` which relies on Client headers to negociate the response content via format listener.

**Solution:**

I changed my configuration to disable FOSRest to disable format listener for HTML pages.

```
fos_rest:
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: '^/rest', priorities: [ 'json' ], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: false }
            #- { path: ^/, priorities: [ 'text/html', '*/*' ], fallback_format: html, prefer_extension: true }
            - { path: '^/', stop: true }
```